# Make a filter so that quotations that already have a calculator do not appear in the select option

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter

How do you create a condition when a Quotation # that already has a Calculation # does not appear / hide in the select list? So for example Calculation # with voucher No. CALC/2023/06/0123 already has Quotation # with voucher No. QUO/2023/06/055. Then, if you want to make a new Calculation # then QUO/2023/06/055 will not automatically appear in the selection options in Quotation #.

```
const onSelectProject = (e, name) => {
        const project = projectList.find((item) => item.id === e.id);
        const filteredQuotations = quotationList.filter((item) => item.projectID === project.id);
        setFormData({
            ...formData,
            [name]: e.id,
            quotationRequestID: null,
        });
        setQuotationList(filteredQuotations);
    };

    const onSelectQuotation = (e, name) => {
        let details = calculatorDetails;
        const selectedQuotation = quotationList.find((item) => item.id === e.id);
        const selectedProject = projectList.find((item) => item.id === selectedQuotation.projectID);
        const filteredQuotations = quotationList.filter((item) => item.projectID === selectedProject.id);

        if (selectedQuotation !== undefined && selectedQuotation !== null) {
            let quotationDetail = master.quotationDetail;
            loadQuotationDetail({ id: selectedQuotation.id });
            if (quotationDetail.quotationRequestDetails !== undefined && quotationDetail.quotationRequestDetails !== null) {
                quotationDetail.quotationRequestDetails.map((item) => {
                    details.push({
                        id: 0,
                        calculatorID: 0,
                        spesification: item.pic,
                        origin: item.origin,
                        pph: 0,
                        margin: 12,
                        cnf: 0,
                        fc: 0,
                        importDuty: 0,
                        cc: 1000,
                        et: 0,
                        fee: 0,
                        transportaion: 0,
                        freeMaintenance: 820,
                        subTotal1: 0,
                        factoryVisit: 0,
                        additionalCost: 0,
                        subTotal2: 0,
                        oh: 0,
                        subTotal3: 0,
                        procurementVendor: 0,
                        installationVendor: 0,
                        quantityVendor: item.qty === undefined || item.qty === null ? 0 : item.qty,
                        grandTotalVendor: 0,
                        procurementCustomer: 0,
                        installationCustomer: 0,
                        quantityCustomer: item.qty === undefined || item.qty === null ? 0 : item.qty,
                        totalCustomer: 0,

                        vpph: '',
                        vmargin: '',
                        vcnf: '',
                        vfc: '',
                        vimportDuty: '',
                        vcc: '',
                        vet: '',
                        vfee: '',
                        vtransportaion: '',
                        vfreeMaintenance: '',
                        vsubTotal1: '',
                        vfactoryVisit: '',
                        vadditionalCost: '',
                        vsubTotal2: '',
                        voh: '',
                        vsubTotal3: '',
                        vprocurementVendor: '',
                        vinstallationVendor: '',
                        vquantityVendor: '',
                        vgrandTotalVendor: '',
                        vprocurementCustomer: '',
                        vinstallationCustomer: '',
                        vquantityCustomer: '',
                        vtotalCustomer: ''
                    })
                })
            }
            setFormData({ ...formData, calculatorDetails: details })
        }
        setQuotationList(filteredQuotations);
        setFormData({
            ...formData,
            [name]: e.id,
            projectID: selectedProject.id,
            ohb: selectedQuotation.ohb,
            ohbidr: selectedQuotation.ohbidr,

            vohb: numberToString(selectedQuotation.ohb),
            vohbidr: numberToString(selectedQuotation.ohbidr)
        });
    };


<div className="form-group col-sm-6">
                        <label>Calculation #</label>
                        <input className="form-control" type="text" name="voucherNo" value={voucherNo} onChange={isCountReverse ? (e) => onCountReverseChange(e) : (e) => onChange(e)} readOnly />
                    </div>
<div className="form-group col-sm-6">
                        <label>Quotation #</label>
                        <span className="required-star">*</span>
                        <Select2
                            style={{ width: "418px" }}
                            options={quotationList}
                            optionValue={(option) => option.id.toString()}
                            optionLabel={(option) => option.voucherNo}
                            placeholder={"** Please choose quotation"}
                            value={quotationList === null ? null : quotationList.filter((option) =>
                                option.id === parseInt(quotationRequestID)
                            )}
                            handleChange={(e) => onSelectQuotation(e, "quotationRequestID")}
                            isDisabled={projectID === 0}
                            required
                        />
                    </div>
 <div className="form-group col-sm-6">
                        <label>Project Name</label>
                        <span className="required-star">*</span>
                        <Select2
                            style={{ width: "418px" }}
                            options={projectList}
                            optionValue={(option) => option.id.toString()}
                            optionLabel={(option) => option.name}
                            placeholder={"** Please choose project"}
                            value={projectList === null ? null : projectList.filter((option) =>
                                option.id === parseInt(projectID)
                            )}
                            handleChange={(e) => onSelectProject(e, "projectID")}
                            required
                        />
                    </div>
```